# How can I change the value of shape keys using a custom controler?

Tags: python, workflow, shape-keys

By using the value slider I'm able to increase or decrease the *Smile* value of a *Shape Key* in 0.1mm increments. How can I do that using python?

[image]

The image below shows it running in Maya and I'd like changing the *Shape Keys* value in Blender the same way.

[image]

I couldn't find a solution to the question yet so I tried to implement it as follows. Basically I'd like creating a controller and apply *Driven* to *Target* Shape Keys and move them by 0.1mm:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
ob = bpy.context.scene.objects['Smile_Controller'] #Select Smile_Controller

ob.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.1, 0, 0), orient_type='LOCAL',) #0.1mm
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
```

However, I'd prefer to control the *Shape Key* value directly. Each time the button is clicked, the value should increase or decrease by 0.1mm.

**Q:** Is there any way to implement such controls using python?

Comment: Hi and welcome to bse! I took the liberty to edit your question which hopefully makes it easier to understand. if you think my edit does not improve anything, don't hesitate to roll it  back. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your modification.
I will do my best in the future. :)